# Does incorporating methods in main() accounts for time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Suppose a function

```
func(){
    O(N)
}
```

and

```
main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    func();
}
```

Will the time complexity be `Liner` or `Quadratic`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the function is called N times in the second example, the Time complexity will be O(n)*(Time complexity of function f)  in the second case, while in the first case will be O(n) if the function is called once.